# Initialize all missing data points to 0 in Google Visualization chart

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I'm trying to chart the number of records for a certain given ID on an hourly basis from a MySQL database.

The problem I'm having is that if there are 0 records for the given ID during a given hour, I don't generate a data point for the table. This causes the table to interpolate between two counts if there
is no count between the hours.

ex: 4 records at 1pm, 0 records at 2pm, 2 records at 3pm. The table will draw a straight line between 4 and 2 so it would appear on the table that there were 3 records at 2pm when there were actually none.

I'm sure the reason is that I'm not providing null or 0 values for non-existent records but I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

Some info on the table:

```
id             int AI
TagNumber      int
TimeStamp      timestamp
BatteryStatus  varchar
Location       int
```

Here is the php code I am using to count the number of instances of a given TagNumber on an hourly basis.

```
$result = $mysqli->('SELECT hour(TimeStamp) as Hour, count(*) as Count FROM table WHERE Location = 1 AND TagNumber = 12345678 GROUP BY Hour');
// The values here are hard coded for testing purposes. 

$rows = array();
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'Hour', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Count', 'type' => 'number')
);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Hour']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Count']);
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}
$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
```

I then pass the json encoded table to google visualization api.

What I believe I need to do is set every hour between 1 and 24 that does not have a record returned from the mysql query set to 0, I just have no idea how to achieve that.

I tried initializing an array of Hours from 1 to 24 with 0 as the 'Count' value, but I'm definitely doing something wrong and the php is throwing errors. [image]

The point at 12 should read 0, but instead it interpolates between 11 and 13.

Here is my chart with values:

- Hour 10 -> Count 4
- Hour 11 -> Count 2
- Hour 13 -> Count 1
- Hour 14 -> Count 3

In this case, I would needs hours 1->9, 12, and 15->24 to show a 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = $mysqli->('SELECT hour(TimeStamp) as Hour, count(*) as Count FROM table WHERE Location = 1 AND TagNumber = 12345678 GROUP BY Hour');
// The values here are hard coded for testing purposes. 

$rows = array();
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'Hour', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Count', 'type' => 'number')
);

$hoursNotAvail = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Hour']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Count']);
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    $hoursNotAvail[(int) $row['Hour']] = -1;
}
foreach($hoursNotAvail as $k => $v){
    if($v != -1){
        $temp = array();
        $temp[] = array('v' => $k);
        $temp[] = array('v' => 0);
        $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
```

Comment: Thanks I ended up doing something very similar in the end. Works great